# How to hide bottom TabLayout once keyboard shows up?

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-softkeyboard, android-tablayout

I am using bottom `TabLayout` with `ViewPager` above the tabs, XML listed below:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_wrapper"
        layout="@layout/toolbar_main" />

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs_bottom_main"
        style="@style/AppTabLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        app:tabGravity="fill" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view_black_line"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_above="@id/tabs_bottom_main"
        android:background="@android:color/black" />

    <NonSwipableViewPager
        android:id="@+id/view_pager_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@id/view_black_line"
        android:layout_below="@id/toolbar_wrapper"
        android:background="@android:color/white" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

When the keyboard shows up, the whole `View` pushed up, I would like to hide the bottom `TabLayout` only (but keep the `ViewPager` above) once the keyboard shows up. How to achieve it?

**P.S.**

I have tried listening the keyboard show up event and set `TabLayout` visibility with `mBottomTabLayout.setVisibility(isOpen ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);`

But this will hide the whole `ViewPager` together with the `TabLayout`.

Comment: put **android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateVisible|stateAlwaysHidden"** in **<activity>** inside menifest file.

Comment: @RahulSharma that would apply to the `ViewPager` also, which is not what OP wants.

Comment: try to take **LinearLayout** with orientation **Vertical** as a parent. And then try your **VISIBILITY** logic as you mentioned above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works after I change `RelativeLayout` to `LinearLayout` according to @Rahul Sharma's advice.

Then I used the [KeyboardVisibilityEvent](https://github.com/yshrsmz/KeyboardVisibilityEvent) library:

```
KeyboardVisibilityEvent.setEventListener(this,
            new KeyboardVisibilityEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onVisibilityChanged(boolean isOpen) {
                    mBottomTabLayout.setVisibility(isOpen ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 2):

Add this to your manifest under activity tag in which you want to hide the TabLayout:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```